# Почему  не могу перевести в нижний регистр переменную

Tags: php

Почему не могу перевести в нижний регистр переменную

```
list($name, $firstname) = explode(" ", $_POST["name_firstname"]);
$a = strtolower($name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кодировка строки не совпадает с текущей системной кодировкой PHP.
Можно изменить кодировку строки или PHP, можно использовать [`mb_strtolower`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtolower.php) указывая конкретную кодировку.

Comment: а как изменить кодировку PHP. В конфигурации apache и кодировки файлах у меня utf-8 стоит

Answer (score 0):

Функция `strtolower()` преобразует только латиницу. Кириллицу функция игнорирует. 
Возможно дело в этом.

[Ссылка на официальную документацию.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtolower.php)

Comment: Не совсем так. Функция прекрасно работает с любыми однобайтными кодировками, той же windows-1251. utf ей конечно не по зубам.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
list($name, $firstname) = explode(" ", $_POST["name_firstname"]);  
echo mb_strtolower($name, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

В принципе ответы верны, добавлю уточнение.

1) Указывайте явно где нибудь в файле конфигурации, что для `mb_` функций используется кодировка UTF-8, по умолчанию стоит другая.

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

В нижний регистр привести можно функцией `mb_strtolower()`